# upload image on edit Axios + Bootstrap Modal in Laravel 9

Tags: jquery, laravel, axios, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to upload an image in a Laravel 9 project using both Axios and a Bootstrap modal.

When I click on the 'Edit' button jQuery will open a Bootstrap Modal named `editCategoryModal` with the help of the `editCategory` function and when I submit the form another function will handle the submission using Axios. In the Controller I used the `UpdateCategory` function to handle the data save into the database.

I don't understand the things that need to be done when using it with Axios in order to submit the image from Bootstrap Modal and send it to Controller in order to move the image to specific folder & save it in database...?!

```html
<div class="edit">
  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success edit-item-btn" onclick="editCategory({{ $category }})">Edit</button>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="editCategoryModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="editModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header bg-light p-3">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="editModalLabel">Edit Category</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" id="close-modal"></button>
      </div>
      <form id="EditForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        <div class="modal-body">
          <input type="hidden" name="categoryid_efield" id="categoryid_efield">
          <div class="mb-3 form-group">
            <label for="categoryname_efield" class="form-label">Category Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="categoryname_efield" id="categoryname_efield" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Category Name" />
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3 form-group">
            <label for="selectImagee" class="form-label">Category Image:</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="file" name="selectImagee" id="selectImagee">
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3 form-group">
            <label for="displayImagee" class="form-label"></label>
            <img class="img-thumbnail" name="displayImagee" id="displayImagee" alt="200x200" width="200" src="https://www.ubertheme.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/edd/2014/06/jm-category.png" data-holder-rendered="true">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <div class="hstack gap-2 justify-content-end">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
function editCategory(e) {
  var categoryId = e.id;
  var categoryName = e.category_name;
  var displayImage = "";
  if (e.category_image == null) {
    displayImage = 'uploads/Noimagefound.jpg';
  } else {
    displayImage = 'uploads/categories/' + e.category_image;
  }
  $("#categoryid_efield").val(categoryId);
  $("#categoryname_efield").val(categoryName);
  $('#displayImagee').attr('src', displayImage);
  $('#editCategoryModal').modal('show');
}


$('body').on('submit', '#EditForm', function(e) {
  let id = $('#categoryid_efield').val();
  let data = {
    id: id,
    categoryName: $('#categoryname_efield').val(),
    categoryImage: document.querySelector('#selectImagee'),
  }
  let url = window.location.origin;
  let path = url + '/categories/update' + '/' + id;
  axios.post(path, data, {
      header: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }
    })
    .then(res => {
      /*$('#editCategoryModal').modal('toggle');
      location.reload();*/
      console.log(res)
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
})
```

categoryController.php:

```php
public function UpdateCategory(Request $request, $id) 
{
  $validated = $request->validate([
    'categoryName' => 'required|max:255',
  ]);
  $data = "";
  if ($request->file('categoryImage'))
  {
    $file = $request->file('categoryImage');
    $filename = date('YmdHi').$file->getClientOriginalName();
    $file->move(public_path('uploads/categories'),$filename);
    $data = $filename;
  }
  $categoryInfo = CategoriesList::find($id)->update([
    'category_name' => $request->categoryName,
    'category_image' => $data,
  ]);
  return Redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Category Updated Successfully!');
}
```

Comment: @rory-mccrossan I know I'm bad in English but with that many correction you distroy my motivation completely 

Comment: The grammar in your post was good! The main purpose of my edit was to add some paragraphs to make it easier to read :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i really appreciate what you did. I'm just kidding a little 

Comment: since you like to fill up modal after edit you should return data from controller like image path , name , success/fail message....

Comment: @bobi in Controller i rename the image by adding date() than image actual name after that i move it into specific folder which is public/uploads/categories. Can you do this in jQuery ? Because if i do i may able to only pass image name in Axios so Controller can save it in databae but how this can be done...?!

Comment: use AIOX only to send and revice information in controller create array that hold all information and then return results return response()->json(['name' => $filename, 'path'=> $path, 'success' = $status]); Then in aiox you have access to this data and simple you can replace/fill up the html

Comment: The fill process works perfectly and save for text data in Edit mode works too. My only issue that i can not save the image file only in database where other field works fine.

Comment: @bobi when I try to console.log(formData) on form submit. It display Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'formData' before initialization at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous>. Why is that...?!  https://codeshare.io/Jbwr3q

Comment: @Q8Xbox because of wrong refference to form, look at this example how should be done
https://jsfiddle.net/sgdkLpxz/12/

Comment: @bobi Thanks it is work fine using formData but why this code document.getElementById('EditForm');  works but this one $('#EditForm'); not ?

Comment: if i remember correctly document.getElementById('EditForm');  return HTML DOM Object and $('#EditForm'); return currect Object